# Creating a New Excel Spreadsheet from a Dynamic Listbox in an MS Access Form

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, listbox, ms-access-2013

I have a search engine built on a form in MS Access. The form uses a ListBox ("List1") to show results based on a keyword search. I wanted to create a button ("Command47") that will show results of listbox in a new excel spreadsheet. I do not want to save the file to a filepath, just want it to open. Below is what I currently have:

```
Private Sub Command47_Click()

      Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef

      Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("VFE")

      qdef.SQL = Me.List1.RowSource

      qdef.Close

      Set qdef = Nothing

      CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "VFE"

End Sub
```

Need to know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do, basically, is open an instance of Excel, create a workbook object, and populate it with the recordset.

In order for this to work, you'll have to add a reference to **Microsoft Excel** *versionnumber* **Object Library**

[References window example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5h0p.png)

```
Private Sub Command47_Click()
  Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef, rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim xl As Excel.Application, wbk As Excel.Workbook, wsh As Excel.Worksheet
  Dim i As Long
  Set qd = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("VFE")
  qd.SQL = Me.List1.RowSource
  Set rs = qd.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)

  Set xl = New Excel.Application
  xl.visible = False
  Set wbk = xl.Workbooks.Add(1)   ' Creates a new workbook with 1 worksheet
  Set wsh = wbk.Worksheets(1)     ' Selects the first worksheet
  With wsh
    .Name = left(qd.Name, 32)
    .Range("A1").Value = qd.Name
    For i = 1 To rs.Fields.Count  ' Populates the 2nd row with field names
      With .cells(2, i)
        .Value = rs.Fields(i - 1).Name
        .font.bold = True
      End With
    Next
    .Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset rs
  End With
  xl.visible = True
  qd.close
  CurrentDB.QueryDefs.Delete("VFE")
End Sub
```

I hope that helps!